# Passing Strings through Structs

Tags: c

So I've got a struct called stationInfo, which has a bunch of info, including latitude, longitude, and station ID. I have written a function that will puts reads from a file and stores the values into arrays of structs. Now, I want to move those arrays of structs into another array of structs.

```
MapMarker mapInfo[t];
int k;
for(k=0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++){
    mapInfo[k].location.latitude = stationInfo[k].location.latitude;
    mapInfo[k].location.longitude = stationInfo[k].location.longitude;
    char* stationName = getStationName(stationInfo[k].stationID);
    strcpy(mapInfo[k].markerName, stationName);
}
```

However, this is breaking my program. How can I fix this?

EDIT: As per Paddy's request:

mapMarker Struct:

```
typedef struct{
GeographicPoint location;
char markerName[100];
char markerText[1000];
int type;
} MapMarker;
```

GeographicPoint location is split into a latitude and logitude struct.

```
char* getStationName(int stationID){
if (stationID < 0 || stationID >= MAX_STATIONS || !AllStationNames[stationID])
    return "Unknown";
return AllStationNames[stationID];
} /* getStationName */
```

And the Array

```
char *AllStationNames[MAX_STATIONS] = {
[1] = "Ian Stewart Complex/Mt. Douglas High School",
[3] = "Strawberry Vale Elementary School",
...
[197] = "RASC Victoria Centre",
[199] = "Trial Island Lightstation",
[200] = "Longacre",
};
```

Comment: Show your `MapMarker` struct definition.  Also, you should show `getStationName`.

Comment: There you are. P.S You're my hero Paddy :)

Comment: What is the value of `t` you are using for the VLA declaration of `mapInfo`?  Surely you meant to use `MAX_STATIONS`.

Comment: I was going to use MAX_STATIONS, but I thought that t gives me the ammount of stations I truely have, so why declare any more than that. But now that I look at it, its probably just better to have it as MAX_STATIONS.

Comment: Well, if `t` can be *less* than `MAX_STATIONS`, you will have a buffer overrun.  I don't see anything wrong with the `strcpy`.  Using `strncpy` is safer, but I think the problem is mismatching the array size with the number of elements you are writing to.  Of course, you could just loop to `t` instead of `MAX_STATIONS`.

Comment: I'm wondering why it causes it to crash though, any idea? also, can I just make an array = a string like I've done? Or do I need to use strcpy there too? EDIT: Okay, so the 2nd part using strcpy works fine, but the first part seems to cause an error, so should I use strcpy?

Comment: It's not the `strcpy`.  It's the fact that you only declare `t` elements, but write data to elements past the end of the array.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense, so if I make MapMarker mapInfo[MAX_STATIONS], but change my loop to for(k=0; k < t; k++), it will still work well and I won't get any unknown returns. That fixes all my problems :D. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you are declaring a VLA (variable-length array) using the variable `t` as size.  That is always less than or equal to `MAX_STATIONS`.  So you have a buffer overrun issue.

```
MapMarker mapInfo[t];
int k;
for(k=0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++){
    // Accessing mapInfo[k] when k >= t will have undefined behaviour
}
```

The simplest solution is to make `mapInfo` constant-size and loop to `t`:

```
MapMarker mapInfo[MAX_STATIONS];
for( k = 0; k < t; k++ ) ...
```